# Bulk image downloader for anime image boards?

Tags: gratis, windows-7, images, scraping

I am looking for a bulk image downloader for anime image boards.

For example: grab/download all photos that are tagged under ['Uta+no☆prince-sama♪' from zerochan.net](http://www.zerochan.net/Uta+no%E2%98%86prince-sama%E2%99%AA) in bulk and have the ability to choose where to save all of the downloaded pictures.

Currently under the tag there are 14,168 images. I want to be able to download them all at once and save them to a specified folder. Is there a program that can do this or a way I could possibly do it without having to right click every single picture and saving it manually?

Required features:

- Must be gratis/free.
- Must be able to run without administrator privileges.
- Can bulk download images in same size and quality.
- Can be any program but must support zerochan.net or be able to download all the images in bulk from zerochan.net. Edit: I wouldn't mind one for Google Image Search.
- Lightweight.
- Good user interface and not complicated to use.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [python](http://www.python.org) + [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) to create a web crawler that will take your start URL, some rules for following links and an image pipeline which will grab and save the required images, (generating thumbnails on the way), *I think you will also need to install PIL or PILLOW*.

- Free (both Gratis & FOSS)
- Flexable
- Will let you set the location to save to
- Only downloads each image once even if it is linked to several times.
- Cross platform so will work on multiple computers.
- The tutorials walk you through what you need to do.
- Will also on sites that require authentication as well as less strict ones.
- Active & helpful usergroup on the mailing lists.

*Do be* ***sure*** *to check with the site(s) that you are planning on downloading from so as to make sure that your intended use of the images is compatible with their terms and conditions.*

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a web crawler or website copier.

If you want to try a quick and easy crawler, look at [FoxySpider](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyspider/), an extension for Firefox. It's very easy to install, configure, and use. I've successfully used it for similar purposes to what you're describing.

You can also use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/), a free GPL website copier. It can take a few minutes to set up your configuration, but can be a very powerful tool. Quick install and pretty good documentation too.